# interface bonding OpenSuse 10.2

Tags: linux, networking, opensuse, bonding

Thanks for taking a look...

I have a very old active OS, unfortunatly due to supplier issues I cannot upgrade to a newer version but I need to get Interface bonding active.

The OS is OpenSUSE 10.2 and added the following lines to /etc/modprobe.conf.local:

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 miimon=100 mode=4 lacp_rate=1
```

and created a new file in /etc/sysconfig/network called ifcfg-bond0
with:

```
DEVICE=bond0
STARTMODE='onboot'
BONDING_MASTER='yes'
BONDING_SLAVE_1=eth0
BONDING_SLAVE_2=eth1
USERCONTROL='no'

IPADDR=172.23.4.137/23
NETWORK=172.23.4.0
BROADCAST=172.23.5.255
GATEWAY=172.23.4.254
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

On the ifcfg files of the physical interfaces:

```
DEVICE=eth0
STARTMODE=auto
BOOTPROTO=none
USERCONTROL=no
MASTER=bond0
```

for eth1 the same except the DEVICE name ofcourse.

The bond0 interface is brought up, but the HW address is 00:00:00:00:00:00
and the txqueuelen is also 0 
No default gateway is set and when trying to do a ping or anything the error is: Network is unreachable

I tried several other options that work perfectly on CentOS or Ferdora (all newer OSes) but not on this old OpenSUSE 10.2 OS.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: I sort of got it working by typing the following command: "ifenslave bond0 eth0 eth1" on the command line. but after a reboot that is lost. I need to have it working automatically at boot.

Answer (score 1):

Added the following line to the /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S05network start script:

```
ifenslave bond0 eth0 eth1
sleep 2
```

and changed the following in the config files: /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-bond0

```
DEVICE=bond0
STARTMODE=onboot
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
USERCONTROLLED=no
BONDMASTER=yes
IPADDR=172.23.4.237
NETMASK=255.255.254.0
```

/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
STARTMODE=onboot
BOOTPROTO=none
USERCONTROL=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth1

```
DEVICE=eth1
STARTMODE=onboot
BOOTPROTO=none
USERCONTROL=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

/etc/sysconfig/network/routes

```
default 172.23.4.254 0.0.0.0 -
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 172.23.5.254
nameserver 172.23.3.254
search nmc
```

And added the following lines to: /etc/modprobe.conf.local

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 mode=4 miimon=100 lacp_rate=1
```

even after restart the interfaces are brought up fine and the cisco switch accepts this config (with config line: channel-group  mode active)

Reminder this is on OpenSuse 10.2 that works for me. On CentOS 6.x and 7.x and Fedora 20+ it works a little different.